# Write to multiple files in Haskell

Tags: haskell, monads, io-monad

In Haskell, how would one go about writing to an arbitrarily large number of files?

As an example, let's say I want to take the letters `a` through `z` and put them in files named for the letter of their contents. An initial attempt was to do the following:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
       let letter = map (:"") ['a'..'z']
       zipWith writeFile letter letter
```

which produced the following error:

> Couldn't match expected type 'IO ()' with actual type '[IO ()]'

I feel like there should be a way to loop through a list in a do block, but I haven't been able to find it yet.

Comment: Maybe you could fold your `zipWith` with dummy actions so that you end up with the correct type ?

Comment: @bli The thing I'm struggling with here is that I want the type to be `[IO ()]` since I want to perform multiple IO actions. I feel like there should be a way for the do block to accept a list, or flatten it out for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you need is [zipWithM](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:zipWithM).

Re. `way to loop through a list in a do block`, there is also a function for this - [sequence](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:sequence), so you can write `sequence $ zipWith writeFile letter letter`.

Comment: I also had to change the type of main to `main :: IO [()]`, but that did it for me. Thanks.

Comment: @martin That is an option, though it's more common to leave `main :: IO ()` and add `return ()` as the last entry in the `do` block, after the `zipWithM` line.

Comment: @martin ...or, even better, use the `zipWithM_` variant which does not even return the useless list of units `[()]` in the first place.